# Running a .war and WSDL file

Tags: java, web, wsdl, war

I have been sent across a .war and WSDL file from a company to demonstrate an application.
I need help deploying this on my local machine please?
I instantly thought to use WAMP but it seems that isnt the case.

Any advice (in as much detail as you can please) would be truly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't you be contacting the company first?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself properly, I have been sent it to look at. Please don't worry about the issues regarding running it as that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the war file locally in any of the web containers such as Tomcat. If you want to do it on Tomcat then simply put the war file in Tomcat/webapps dir and start the tomcat form bin/startup.exe or bin/startup.sh.

Once you have the war deployed, and I assume the webservices are part of that war, then you can try hitting the desired WSDL url on your local tomcat. If all goes fine, then URL should return the WSDL.

Comment: so is tomcat like WAMP? A tool I download that runs it on my local machine?

Comment: @Programatt I believe WAMP is to deploy php based web apps. I am not sure much about it, tomcat is used to deploy war files containing java code.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a go now before I approve your answer :)